# Regex validation for comma separated string

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to validate and input string client side.

Here is an example of the string:

```
1:30-1:34, 1:20-1:22, 1:30-1:37,
```

It's basically time codes for a video.

Can this be done with regex?

Banging my head against the wall...

Comment: What are your requirements?  Does the second number have to be larger than the first?  Is the pattern always #:##, up to 9999:59?  It will not be very easy to make sure the range is always valid with regex.

Comment: What would be considered a good/bad string for validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a simple representation. I have assumed that the string has the exact same form as you have shown. This may be a good starting point for you. I'll improve the regex if you provide more specific requirements.

> ([0-9]+:[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]+:[0-9]{1,2},\w*)+

Explanation (inspired from Tim above)

> [0-9]+   #One ore more digits 
>   :       # A colon
>   [0-9]{1,2}  #A single digit or a pair of digits
>   -       #A dash
>   ,        #A comma
>   \w*      #Optional whitespace

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:\b\d+:\d+-\d+:\d+\b(?:, )?)+$
```

would probably work; at least it matches your example. But you might need to add a few edge cases to make the rules for matching/not matching clearer.

```
^        # Start of string
(?:      # Try to match...
 \b      # start of a "word" (in this case, number)
 \d+     # one or more digits
 :       # a :
 \d+     # one or more digits
 -       # a dash
 \d+     # one or more digits
 :       # a :
 \d+     # one or more digits
 \b      # end of a "word"
 (?:, )? # optional comma and space
)+       # repeat one or more times
$        # until the end of the string
```